# Storage server with NTFS and Linux on old machine

Tags: windows, samba, ntfs

We have several old computers at home, and many IDE HDD drives. I would like to make a "storage server" from one. SO I want to use its storage as a shared folder. The other computers are Windows 7 / XP. Reqirements:

- Best config: Pentium II, 256 / 384 MB RAM, 200GB+120GB+120GB, with LAN
- no raid is needed
- I would like to format the non-linux partitions as NTFS (so if linux dies, I put the hdd in win computer it can handle)
- Read/write is needed
- I would like to share the partitions root on SMB (so accessible by windows)
- No gui for the "server" - only ssh is needed.

What do you propose for me, with distro / version is good? I am familiar with debian, ubuntu and centos.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu can be installed on a pentium II with 384 MB RAM.
Ubuntu Server has a recommended minimum of a 300 Mhz processor and 128 MB RAM.

If I needed to build a fileSERVER I would go with the obvious and install the headless Ubuntu Server. And would keep it clean, without a Graphic User Interface.
Both systems build from the same source.. The Server edition has no GUI so I believe it will always be lighter in use and can put more resources into the job at hand..

I think Lubuntu is not going to be all that smooth (Got it running on a HP9010 laptop, 1.2 P4 512MB RAM, works reasonably smooth, but it's a good practice in patience)..

Comment: and what about debian server? which is the better regarding resource use? can it still handle ntfs? And how to format disks as ntfs without gui (i had a try in vmware, but needed gparted which needs gtk+)

Comment: I don't know much about debian server but I think it's comparable to ubuntu server. NTFS should not be a problem for ubuntu server, the ntfs-3g driver is pre-installed in all current versions. I think you can format the disk to ntfs on install, but I'm not sure. Alternatively (and I would recommend it) you could use a small disk (ext4) to run your server and use one or more separate disks (formatted in NTFS) to store your data. All nice and clean, easy to maintain.

Comment: you can't use gparted on a gui free server. you will need to use something like fdisk. You can find a step by step guide [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_1000631_hard-drive-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet with be to use Lubuntu.  Lubuntu uses the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment, as its default GUI.  It has very lax system requirements.  You can go [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu) to get more information about Lubuntu, and to download it.

Comment: my problem with lubuntu 13.04 is that i tried to install in vmware, but during the installation process it asks for login which was not specified before... (same with xubuntu) - tried in vmware workstation

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: cannot install with gui! asks for user credentials BEFORE creating user

Comment: Can you add an image that shows that?

Comment: about 10 hrs after now, after my exam

Comment: solved install server, then lxde, default 32bit l/x ubuntu installers just suck, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a gui, just download the server iso, install it and apt-get the packages you need. Once you setup ssh you don't even need a monitor. You might want to look into setting up JBOD to join all the HD's into one logical volume. [How to set up multiple hard drives as one volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7002/how-to-set-up-multiple-hard-drives-as-one-volume/7841#7841)

Of course there is always FreeNAS, which is also really easy. Just be sure to install freeNAS to a bootable USB drive because whatever the boot drive size, FreeNAS claims it and you cannot use it for storage.

Comment: Make that the 12.04 LTS Server. The 13.04 version is 64-bit only: a P II is not up to spec for that.

Comment: is freenas much better than smb? can work with NTFS and windows homegroup (mshome, xp) lan?

Comment: freenas is awesome!! I tried it, but problem: got one core and 256 MB ram, with two virtual disks (stripe). When I write or read, the vm uses the 60-80 (!) percent of one (i5-2500K, 3,3 ghz) core!!! (no cpu difference if non-vm). Is it vm or freenas problem? I can give up ntfs if freenas is ok for PII

Comment: I've used freenas on an old p3 with, if i recall, 192 mb of ram and I had no problems... Granted I am not serving lots of people... Just me and whatever I was playing video/audio on...