# How to increase server space(ubuntu)?

Tags: 16.04, server, disk-usage, postgresql

Now I have server on Ubuntu with PostgreSQL only. What will happen when the HDD's space runs out?

If I'll add one more HDD will data will be writing in it?
Will it increase the available space?

Comment: if you add HDD's and format them into the same partition it should add more space

Comment: I have one hdd now - /dev/sda1. I need to connect one more hdd and it's space plus to /dev/sda1. Yes?

Comment: yes, from what I know that should be it. But I have never had my own server so do it at your own risk

Comment: If you installed the OS using LVM, then see [Adding Disks With LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458476/adding-disks-with-lvm). Otherwise, things will be more complicated (you can't really "format them into the same partition").