# Extending LVM partitions with an external drive

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I am currently running an Ubuntu server, mainly for Plex. I only have one 1TB drive currently installed in the machine, but I am slowly running out of drive space.

If I were to buy another drive for my machine, how would I mount it in such a way that I can increase the size of my current partitions? I don't want to have my Plex files and others split between two different partitions and two different directories.

Basically, I want to keep being able to put my files in the same location but have that extra space if that makes sense.

EDIT:

Output for the command `sudo lvdisplay`

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                rHxUCD-hZMK-eqfL-O6fq-9aLS-ILJB-FoZglK
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2021-11-22 23:52:49 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <930.51 GiB
  Current LE             238210
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

Comment: How have you configured the storage on your server? Is it using an LVM? If so, you can add the new drive(s) to the pool and everything will “just work” 

Comment: @matigo lvdisplay does output a logical volume so I believe i'm using a LVM but my knowledge is very thin so not 100% sure if its setup correctly. See edit for lvdisplay output

Comment: It looks to be set up correctly, so [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/459176/1222991) from a few years ago should give you everything you need to add a drive to the LVM ‍

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Disks With LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458476/adding-disks-with-lvm)