# How to completely clean disk previously used in Windows?

Tags: hard-drive

I used to have Windows installed with an SSD and an HDD. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the SSD, but now I want to use the HDD in Ubuntu as well which still has some remaining files from when my laptop was Windows.

My searches on cleaning up disk only told me how to clean up cache and whatnot. I want to completely delete all files. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I keep running out of space and I have a second disk that I can use, how to format and make accessible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652361/i-keep-running-out-of-space-and-i-have-a-second-disk-that-i-can-use-how-to-form)

Answer (score 0):

*" I want to completely delete all files."*

You can use bootable Ubuntu installation media to use a live session.  This is the "Try Ubuntu" option.

Once you are in a live session, you can use the "Disks" application to format your local hard drive(s).  If you have anything on or connected to the device that you want to keep, make sure you choose the correct disk, because formatting a disk will effectively erase everything.