# Merging all disks in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk-management, merge

My hard disk is 4x10 TB so i would like use all storage as 40 TB. I shared my disk info also i used no raid.  Is there any way to do that. I tried to remove disk but i got error for that. I have "sda", "sdb","sdc", "sdd" and i already use sda as / . So "sdb", "sdc", "sdd" i could not them. i would like use other storage. Thanks helping from now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTAk2.png)

Edit: I tried to mount other disks which are sdc and sdd so i got that now can i use /dev/sdd and /dev/sdc storages. I mean that for example if i use /raif or /ibrahim, storage will be used for sdd or sdc area or Will it be spent from the common area which is totally 18T storage which sda / .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Okh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up multiple hard drives as one volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7002/how-to-set-up-multiple-hard-drives-as-one-volume)

Comment: The disadvantage of LVM across multiple devices, is that if any one fails, you lose all data on all drives, or your 40GB  backup must be very good. You also may improve performance with smaller / (root) partition. Or just add a small SSD as boot drive and then use all 4 drives as data. Best to also gpt partition and use partition(s) for ease of backup.

Comment: If I had 4 x 10 TB drives, I would make a [RAID-Z1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#RAID_(%22RAID-Z%22)) (with 1 disk worth of parity), this will effectively give you ~30 TB data storage, with snapshots, error correction and parity built-in with the filesystem. And in this case, you can replace a faulty disk without loosing data.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, Logical Volume Management, or [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), can be used to create single logical volumes of multiple partitions and hard disks. There are guides available on how to set up and manage logical volumes, e.g. the [Ubuntu wiki on LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) or this [How-to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/) article.

For home use, just organizing your data over the existing 10 TB volumes may, however, be a far easier solution.