# Why is the read/write speed of two SSDs so slow when mounted as single logical volume with LVM under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, ssd, lvm, io

For scientific computing, we need fast read/write speeds. So I upgraded one of our machines with 2 SSDs. I used the command

```
hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
```

to test the read speed. As reference, our standard HDDs have a read speed of 250MB/s.
Each SSD separately has a tested read speed of 2000MB/s (roughly expected).

However, when I connect the two SSDs to one logical volume (following the top-voted answer here: [How to set up multiple hard drives as one volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7002/how-to-set-up-multiple-hard-drives-as-one-volume)), then the read speed of the logical volume is only 200MB/s – much slower than the individual SSDs and even slower than the HDDs…

Is this normal? My understanding of LVM is very basic. I thought files are written to both SSDs simultaneously and therefore the read speed of the combined logical volume might even be higher than that of one single SSD. I also expect some overhead of the LVM, so I do not expect the read speed to be twice that of a single SSD. But only 10% the speed of a single SSD?

I guess my question is: is this normal or did I do something wrong? What is the expected read speed for the logical volume and how can I achieve it? As solution, we could just use the two SSDs as individual volumes, but it would be slightly less convenient.
And for the expected I/O speed, I do not expect an exact numerical value, but rather if it is smaller, similar or greater than that of a single SSD.

The two SSDs are

> Samsung 980 1TB PCIe Gen 3.0 x 4 NVMe M.2

and they are connected via

> Ableconn PEXM2-130 Dual PCIe NVMe M.2 SSDs Carrier Adapter.

**EDIT/SOLVED**

I am still not sure what the original problem was, but when I followed this instruction, everything works well: https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/striped-lvm-volumes/
Now, my logical striped volume of two SSDs has a read speed that is slightly above the read speed of a single SSD (~2500MB/s compared to 2000MB/s single). I hope my experience helps other people as well.

Comment: Can you test the two SSDs ***at the same time***, instead of each one separately? Can it be that the controller is the bottleneck?

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, @FedKad. I have tried it, but the controller does not seem to be the bottleneck:
When I test the read speed for both SSDs simultaneously, they both can read with about 2000MB/s.

Comment: Also, can you test with a newer version of Ubuntu like 20.04 or 21.10 (live session)? Please give details on how you use LVM (mirroring, striping, etc.).

Comment: I am afraid it is difficult to test these SSDs in a live session: the machine is a working node of a cluster and can not be rebooted atm. I can test it during the next cluster maintenance.
Mirroring/striping: I am new to LVM and simply followed the guide linked above. So I guess by default I did not set up mirroring/striping. However, I will look into "striping" which might be useful for our purpose. Thanks!
Based on your questions, I guess you also find the small read speed of the SSDs suspicious, right?